# DB2 query to extract data between two delimiters

Tags: sql, select, db2, db2-luw

I need to fix a query on a DB2 version that does not support LOCATE_IN_STRING. The query is of a table that lists file space names and the value is always between the 3rd and 4th '\'. The data in the field looks like this.

```
Unnamed[1]: AMER-AP-DAG\Microsoft Exchange Writer\{76fe1ac4-15f7-4bcd-987e-8e1acb462fb7}\AMER-MB-08\6bc391ef-a370-49a1-8f05-b1bed9-e5ad55

Unnamed[1]: AMER-AP-DAG\Microsoft Exchange Writer\{76fe1ac4-15f7-4bcd-987e-8e1acb462fb7}\Mailbox Database 1303547393\2bc06db2-1966-4fd7-9545-f667102b0b7d

Unnamed[1]: AMER-AP-DAG\Microsoft Exchange Writer\{76fe1ac4-15f7-4bcd-987e-8e1acb462fb7}\APAC-MB-05\11dedbd4-1757-45c8-8991-f0f713-4ef210
```

When I use LOCATE the best I can get is the string I need but it still has all the data after the 4th '\'. Also as you can see the string length can vary but the string always seems to start at character position 78.

```
Select -                                                                        
 SUBSTR(FILESPACE_NAME, LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, - 
 LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME, -                                                  
 LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME)+1)+1)-1)+1) -                                      
 as FSNAME -                                                                    

from filespaces -                                                               
 where node_name='AMER-AP-DAG'
```

FSNAME: AMER-MB-08\6bc391ef-a370-49a1-8f05-b1bed9e5ad55

FSNAME: Mailbox Database 1143943276\55ac1670-efc9-4301-ac5c-beb5cd2d77cb

FSNAME: APAC-MB-05\11dedbd4-1757-45c8-8991-f0f7134ef210

Comment: Which OS and which version?

Comment: Technically its DB2 on AIX but the application in use is a DB2 based backup software from IBM (IBM Spectrum Protect .... formerly TSM). Most queries tend to run cross platform. The DB2 versions that I need this to work with are 9.7 and 10.5. I have it working with LOCATE_IN_STRING with DB2 11.

Comment: Here is the select that works in the latest TSM version which uses DB2 11

    select -
     VARCHAR(NODE_NAME,12) as NODE, -
     varchar(substring(filespace_name, 
     LOCATE_IN_STRING(filespace_name, '\', 1, 3), -
     LOCATE_IN_STRING(filespace_name, '\', 1, 4) - 
     LOCATE_IN_STRING(filespace_name, '\', 1, 3)),30) as Exch_DB, -
     date(backup_end) AS LAST_GOOD_BACKUP -
    from FILESPACES -
     where -
      node_name='AMER-AP-DAG' -
      order by Exch_DB, backup_end asc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will give you the characters between the third and fourth backslashes:

```
Select -
 SUBSTR(FILESPACE_NAME, -
 LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, -
 LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME, -
 LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME)+1)+1)+1, -
 LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, -
 LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, -
 LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME, -
 LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME)+1)+1)+1)- -
 LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, -
 LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME, -
 LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME)+1)+1)-1) -
 as FSNAME -
from filespaces -
 where node_name='AMER-AP-DAG'
```

---

How it works:

To get the positions of the backslashes that delimit the desired text, you are using the LOCATE function, which has the parameters (1) search string, (2) source string, and (3) an optional start position.

The LOCATE statements are finding the position of a backslash, and then using the following character as a starting point to find the next backslash:

{i} Position of character following the first backslash =

```
LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME)+1
```

{ii} Position of character following the second backslash =

```
LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME, LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME)+1)+1
```

{iii} Position of character following the third backslash =

```
LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME, LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME)+1)+1)+1
```

{iv} Position of character following the fourth backslash =

```
LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, LOCATE('\',FILESPACE_NAME, LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME, LOCATE('\', FILESPACE_NAME)+1)+1)+1)+1
```

To extract the text between the backslashes, you are using the SUBSTR function, which has the parameters (1) string expression, (2) start position, and (3) an optional length.

So, to get the characters between the third and fourth backslashes, you just need to set

start = the first character following the third backslash

```
  = {iii}
```

and

length = the number of characters between the third and fourth backslashes
       = position of fourth backslash - position of third backslash - 1

```
   = ({iv} - 1) - ({iii} - 1) - 1
```

Comment: That totally worked! Now I just need to understand how/why.

Comment: Explanation added above.

Comment: So a typical substring looks like this select  substr(filespace_name,<start position>,<length>) so you used the location to start at the 3rd and used 3rd minus 4th '\' positions for length. Totally get it now. I see the subtraction now for length and how you came about it. Thanks so much.